Using Xdebug in PhpStorm to debug Laravel with Vue js application
I have a Laravel backend application and Vue.js 2 frontend application running on Laravel Valet, with SSL enabled. I’ve set up Xdebug with PHP 8.2, and everything works as expected.
When I test API endpoints directly from the browser or from postman, the breakpoints are hit in PhpStorm, confirming that my Xdebug and server configuration in PhpStorm is correct.
However, when the frontend makes API calls to the Laravel backend, the debugger doesn’t stop at breakpoints
Despite setting the frontend URL with port 443 and specifying the absolute backend path in PhpStorm, Xdebug redirects to the Valet path:
/home/ahmed/.config/composer/vendor/cpriego/valet-linux/server.php
The code execution stops at this line:
define('VALET_HOME_PATH', posix_getpwuid(fileowner(__FILE__))['dir'] . '/.valet');
When I try to resume the program, it doesn’t continue to the Laravel code breakpoints.
Also there is no Cookie is set in frontend browser with XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM
even the Xdebug extension is enabled

"Also there is no Cookie is set in frontend browser with XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM" AFAIK this does not set the cookie. Better use Xdebug browser extension to enable/disable Xdebug cookie -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/browser-debugging-extensions.html

@LazyOne Yes I already using Xdebug browser extension, it is already working fine with calling API calls from backend domain, but in frontend domain it is not added

What that extension does, it sets the Xdebug cookie for the current domain. If your API calls go to another domain (e.g. subdomain, or even on a different explicit port (e.g. the website is on mydomain.com and API is on mydomain:3000) then the cookie should not stick. Double check this with your browser Network tab -- see what the request to such an endpoint has (cookies or GET/POST params).

About "The code execution stops at this line:" -- please show a screenshot of what you have at "Settings/Preferences | PHP | Debug" and perhaps "Settings/Preferences | PHP | Servers" as well

You might have to figure out how to add the XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM as GET or POST parameter when the frontend makes API calls.
